# When i wanted to Add Theme qt creator in deploy step get me error

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a qt quick application and it runs on windows without any problem. When I want to run it on android device it will build successfully but in deploy step it gives me the errors that is in below .(I can run other examples of qt on my android device without any problem like "gallery").

> Invalid APK file: D:/Qt/Projects/build-Joor2 -Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_1_for_Android_armv7-Debug/android-build//bin/QtApp-debug.apk
>   Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: Jooya
>   Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
>   Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
>   Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.impl
>   Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl
>   Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Universal.impl
>   Installing to device failed!
>   17:07:30: The process "D:/Qt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 16.
>   17:07:30: Pulling files necessary for debugging.
>   17:07:30: Package deploy: Running command "D:/programing/program/Android-Java/SDK/platform-tools/adb.exe -s 410066dfc826b151 pull /system/bin/app_process32 D:/Qt/Projects/build-JooyaLeitner2-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_1_for_Android_armv7-Debug/app_process".
>   17:07:31: Package deploy: Running command "D:/programing/program/Android-Java/SDK/platform-tools/adb.exe -s 410066dfc826b151 pull /system/lib/libc.so D:/Qt/Projects/build-Joor2 -Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_1_for_Android_armv7-Debug/libc.so".
>   Error while building/deploying project Joor2 (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.9.1 for Android armv7))
>   When executing step "Deploy to Android device"

I integrated c++ with qml as below in main.cpp file

```
 CoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("Jooya");
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain("jooyabash.ir");
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("Jooya Leitner");


QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
qmlRegisterType<LoginManager>("Jooya",1,0,"LoginManager");
qmlRegisterType<MainPage>("Jooya",1,0,"MainPage");

engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    return -1;

return app.exec();
```

and because of the code above I am getting:

> Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: Jooya

I want to know how can I run my application on an android device?

**Edit**

In another qt quick controls 2 ,when i wanted to add splash to my app following the below link

https://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2017/07/qml-show-android-native-splash-screen.html

after doing that it will above error ? does any one can help me?

Comment: please try to provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Please follow below link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240421/unable-to-make-qmlregistertype-work